# Relay or SSR for electrical heating from tado smart thermostat?

Tags: resistors, solid-state-relay

I have a Tado smart thermostat system to switch my electrical underfloor heating.

It offers a simple NO or NC switch. This is rated at up to 6A. (Aside: Tado is not a good company. They provide no data sheet and can't answer questions. I regret giving them money.)

I would prefer to avoid the need for a low-voltage circuit; I'm hoping to get around that with an AC-to-AC SSR.

Question: is my circuit going to work and be safe?

Secondary: am I breaking any conventions?

ORIGINAL DIAGRAM:
[image: AC-to-AC SSR circuit]

AMENDMENT 1:
[image: Amendment to allow minimum input voltage to be met]

Comment: Is the Tado actually rated for switching 230VAC?

Comment: Yes - but please note that this is information I've extracted from scouring the web and speaking to sales personnel rather than from a data sheet.

I also have a smaller heating mat that draws 600W that I am switching directly with the Tado (no relay or SSR). It's been working for a week, but I have the nagging suspicion that it will kill the Tado over time.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is better handled as home improvement

Comment: @ScottSedman: Home Improvement may not be able to answer questions regarding how to control a Solid State Relay.  This question belongs Electronics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the labelling on the SSR is correct then your proposal is fine on the output side - except that you are missing a fuse or circuit-breaker.

The 22k resistor on the input limits the current in a short-circuit to about 10 mA. Since the minimum input voltage is 80 V I suspect that 22k is way to high. The device will accept a 230 V input directly. Again a 500 mA fuse on this circuit would be a good idea.

[image]

*Figure 1. An AC input, AC output SSR.*

SSRs work by using LEDs on the input to trigger a phototransistor on the output side. The optical isolation between the two sides provides the electrical isolation - although your circuit doesn't need it as both sides are fed from the same mains supply.

Your SSR has an AC input. This is indicated by the back-to-back LEDs. (One is pointing down and the other up.) This means that each of them will light on alternate mains half-cycles. The box marked Input Circuit looks after current limiting for the LED. You can apply any voltage between 80 to 250 V AC directly to the input to turn on the output.

Comment: Noted about the fuses - will do.

About the minimum input voltage, will my amended diagram meet that requirement?

Comment: Why do you think you need any resistors?

Comment: You may be exposing my colossal ignorance - I'm a software monkey, not a sparky. But I believe that without any significant resistance, current through the input side will be unrestricted and will exceed 30A, tripping my RCDs and/or melting my Tado...?

Comment: See the update.